# $[h_i,{(ad\ f_i)^t\ f_j}]=-(t\alpha_i+\alpha_j)(h_i){(ad\ f_i)^t\ f_j}$ in a Kac-Moody algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

In Carter's Lie algebras of finite and affine type, when constructing the Weyl group in the setting of a Kac-Moody algebras, Carter uses an identity $[h_i,{(ad\ f_i)^t(f_j)}]=-(t\alpha_i+\alpha_j)(h_i){(ad\ f_i)^t(f_j)}$. I'm having trouble seeing why this is the case? I've tried showing it by induction, but it doesn't seem to get me anywhere (the basecase is just from the defintion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that induction on $t$ works. As you noted, the case $t=0$ follows from the definition. Suppose $[h_i, (ad f_i)^t (f_j)]=-(t\alpha_i + \alpha_j)(h_j)(ad f_i)^t(f_j) $ and write $x=(ad f_i)^t (f_j)$ for simplicity.

Then $(ad f_i)^{t+1}(f_j) = [f_i, x] $ and
\begin{align} [h_i, (ad f_i)^{t+1}(f_j)] &= [f_i, [h_i, x]]-[x,[h_i, f_i]] &&\text{Jacobi identity} \\ &=[f_i, -(t\alpha_i+\alpha_j)(h_i)x]+[x,\alpha_i(h_i)f_i] &&\text{induction hypothesis}\\ &=-(t\alpha_i+\alpha_j)(h_i)[f_i,x]-\alpha_i(h_i)[f_i, x] \\ &=-\left(  (t+1)\alpha_i + \alpha_j \right)(h_i)[f_i, x] \\ &= -\left(  (t+1)\alpha_i + \alpha_j \right)(h_i)(ad f_i)^{t+1}(f_j)
\end{align}

as desired.